# How to run an application right after rejecting a call?

Tags: android

is there any way to run an application right after rejecting a call?

I tried to search for solutions but I couldn't find any.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: use Broadcast Listener, and listen for incoming call. Search google for BroadcastListener, of something like that: "android java intercept a call". SO is a place to help with already existing code, not to do the research for you, or give you finished code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a PhoneStateListener to see when the call is ended. you will most likely need to trigger the listener actions to wait for a the call to start (wait until changed from PHONE_STATE_OFFHOOK to PHONE_STATE_IDLE again) and then write some code to bring your app back up on the IDLE state.

you may need to run the listener in a service to ensure it stays up and your app is restarted. some example code:

```
EndCallListener callListener = new EndCallListener();
TelephonyManager mTM = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mTM.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Listener definition:

```
private class EndCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }
        if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            //wait for phone to go offhook (probably set a boolean flag) so you know your app initiated the call.
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");
        }
        if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            //when this state occurs, and your flag is set, restart your app
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");
        }
    }
}
```